# What does the > arithmetic operator in HLSL do?

Tags: operators, hlsl

I found some code online for a shader containing these lines:

```
float2 preRect;
preRect.x = (IN.uv_MainTex.x > _RectMinX) - (IN.uv_MainTex.x > _RectMaxX);
```

In C based languages `(IN.uv_MainTex.x > _RectMinX)` would evaluate as a boolean but here it's assigning a numeric value to the float preRect.

What is this line doing & how is it doing it?

Thanks

Comment: IIRC `x > y` is a shorthand for `take x if it's greater than y, otherwise y`.

Answer (score 1):

The comment left above is incorrect.

return (a > b) - c;

is equivalent to:

return (a > b ? 1.0f : 0.0f) - c;

Comment: Thanks. Since I've no idea what the answer might be I'll leave this to others to vote :)

Comment: I was afraid of my comment being incorrect. Hence the IIRC disclaimer and no answer from me. :)